# Custom style for textcite with one author

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm using biblatex to organize my bibliography. In case that \textcite{ref} only references a single author, I want to display the shortened first name. See the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, language=USenglish]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{ref1,
  Title                    = {Title 1},
  Author                   = {Duck, Donald and Mouse, Mickey and Goofy, Goofy and Duck, Daisy},
  Year                     = {2012},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {1},
}

@Article{ref2,
  Title                    = {The influenza virus M2 protein cytoplasmic tail interacts with the M1 protein and influences virus assembly at the site of virus budding},
  Author                   = {Duck, Donald},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Month                    = {Oct},
  Number                   = {20},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{ref1}

\textcite{ref2}
\end{document}
```

The output of `\textcite{ref2}` is `Duck [Duc08]`. However, I want it to be `D. Duck [Duc08]`.
The style for more authors should not be changed.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite an inconsistent style, but it is easily possible with `stykle=alphabetic`.

```
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}}
    and test {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}}
    and not test \ifmorenames}
    {\ifuseprefix
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefixi}
         {\namepartsuffixi}}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
```

Comment: How do I use this format? If I put it in the preamble of the document, the names do not show up at all.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. I think there is a `\nameparts{#1}` missing as the first line of the new format.

Comment: @W.Alpha `\nameparts{#1}` is not needed any more in versions newer than 3.4, the current version is 3.8a. So you might want to think about an update.